# Simple google maps marker click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Is it possible to have a simple behaviour using jQuery or js when a user hit a gmap marker?

Simply trying to load some content in an external div using ajax when we hit a marker on the map. Something like this would be a good start (not working tho):

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                alert("ciao");
     });
```

Comment: How are you defining marker?  How is this code associated to that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: hang on, I already have the markers. What I want is to be able to trigger an event on each click

Comment: @rob.m edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: why do I need to define the Lat?

Comment: @rob.m Its the position of the marker